# Can drinking too much water lead to looking bloated?

Tags: water, hydration

I drink a lot of water. Easily 4 liters pure liquid on normal days, 5+ when exercising (5 days a week).

I heard as a child, that salt and water are stored and produce compartments similar to fat.

Is that really true? Is there such a thing as water weight and could I reduce my body size, by cutting back my water intake to 2 liters of liquid a day?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can retain water, but since you are exercising 5+ days a week you *need* that water to help you hydrate and will not retain much of it at all.

> When you exercise, you force the veins to carry back waste products
>   and used-up blood to the heart, which, in turn, cleans that blood,
>   with the aid of other organs. This aids in the secretion (much of it
>   through the bladder) of excess fluids.
>
> People who don’t exercise, on the other hand, often develop swollen
>   limbs, over-burdened organs, and weight gain. Exercise is, in fact,
>   one of your best defenses against water retention.

[Source](http://www.freedrinkingwater.com/water_health/health1/top-five-reasons-people-retain-water.htm)

Comment: That source seems more like a blog post then something authoritative. It doesn't link to research or any evidence.

Comment: It's a well-researched blog post, at any rate -- I certainly couldn't name six categories of drugs, nine diseases, or four nutritional deficiencies that lead to water retention.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have sufficient sodium, your body will do a good job regulating your water level; if you drink too much, you will excrete it.

Comment: Could you elaborate or supply a link on the connection of sodium and water retention? Thanks for your answer.